# Server-side code working with JavaScript using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to get a server side code working with JavaScript. What am I doing wrong?

```
function openUp(name)
{
    document.getElementById(name).style.display =  <%if (Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].Contains("FireFox"))Then %>
        response.write('table-row'); <%else%> response.write('block');
}
```

Comment: For starters, you're trying to build JavaScript dynamically, which is almost always a bad idea. Use classes and `[data-*]` attributes to pass data to the client side, and keep your scripts in external `.js` files.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Response.Write` statement (which is not properly cased) should be inside the `<%  %>` tags. You also seem to have an odd mixture of C# and [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) in your code. Which of the following are you using?

C#

```
document.getElementById(name).style.display =  
    <% if (Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].Contains("FireFox"))
           Response.Write("'table-row'");
       else
           Response.Write("'block'"); %>; // Semi-colon outside of %> is for JavaScript
```

VB.NET

```
document.getElementById(name).style.display =  
    <% If (Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT").Contains("FireFox")) Then
           Response.Write("'table-row'") 
       Else
           Response.Write("'block'")
       End If %>; // Semi-colon outside of %> is for JavaScript
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you can update your code to;

C#

```
document.getElementById(name).style.display = '<%Response.Write((Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].Contains("FireFox") ? "table-row": "block")); %>';
```

VB

```
document.getElementById(name).style.display = '<%Response.Write(IIF(Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].Contains("FireFox"), "table-row", "block")) %>';
```